# TIdTCPServer disconnect a client totally from the server

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I am using `TIdTCPServer`. I have a client that has disconnected abnormally.
 I am trying to disconnect this client like the following:

```
//class TClientConnection = class(TIdServerContext)

var
  Clienttodisconnect: TClientConnection;

List := Server.Contexts.LockList;
try
  for I := 0 to List.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Clienttodisconnect := TClientConnection(List.Items[I]);
    if Clienttodisconnect.uuid = idtodiscnnect then
    begin
      try    
        Clienttodisconnect.Connection.Disconnect;    
      except
      end;
    end;
  end;
finally
  Server.Contexts.UnlockList;
end;
```

Sometimes the client gets disconnected from the server, and sometimes it gets stuck until the server is restarted.

What am I doing wrong? I just want to disconnect the client from the context.

here is the server onexecute event

```
var
  Connection: TClientConnection;
  CMD: String;
  Cache, OutboundCmds: TStringList;
  I: integer;
  UConnected : Boolean;
  Len: Integer;
begin

sleep(10);

Try
UConnected := AContext.Connection.Connected;
Except
UConnected := False;
End;

If UConnected <> True Then
begin
AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
exit;
end;

Len := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size;


If Len >= 200000 then
begin
AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
exit;

end;

Connection := AContext as TClientConnection;



  // check for pending outbound commands...
  OutboundCmds := nil;
  try
    Cache := Connection.OutboundCache.Lock;
    try
      if Cache.Count > 0 then
      begin
        OutboundCmds := TStringList.Create;
        OutboundCmds.Assign(Cache);
        Cache.Clear;
      end;
    finally
      Connection.OutboundCache.Unlock;
    end;

    if OutboundCmds <> nil then
    begin
      for I := 0 to OutboundCmds.Count - 1 do
      begin
        AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Writeln(OutboundCmds.Strings[I],
          IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
      end;
      Connection.LastSendRecv := Ticks64;
    end;




  finally
    if OutboundCmds <> nil then
    begin
      for I := 0 to OutboundCmds.Count - 1 do
      begin
        OutboundCmds.Objects[I].Free;
      end;
    end;
    OutboundCmds.Free;
  end;

  // check for a pending inbound command...
  if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
  begin
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(100);
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDisconnect;
    if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
    begin
    if GetElapsedTicks(Connection.LastSendRecv) >= 30000 then
     AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
     Exit;
    end;
  end;

.......

........
```

Comment: Where does the `idtodiscnnect` come from? The rest (except that exception eating and no exit from loop when you find the right client) seems to be fine.

Comment: Don't leave the except block naked! Always log the error (or show it in a dialog or somewhere), it could give you important info for your debug process

Comment: @Victoria `idtodiconnect` is a const parameter that sent from the client side to the server .

Comment: i did some log tracing in on exception block and it did not raise any exception while disconnecting abnormal disconnected client .

Comment: What does your `OnExecute` handler look like? How it is coded has a big impact on how `TIdTCPServer` processes disconnects. And the code shown in this question is not the safest way to disconnect a client anyway. Best to handle that in the `OnExecute` event instead. Use timeouts, or flag the `TClientConnection` and have `OnExecute` look for that flag, so `Disconnect()` can be called in the thread that owns the client connection.

Comment: @RemyLebeau onExecute event added to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest something more like this:

```
type
  TClientConnection = class(TIdServerContext)
  public
    Cache: TIdThreadSafeStringList;
    uuid: string; // or TGuid or whatever you are using...
    ForceDisconnect: Boolean; // <-- add this
  end;

...

var
  List: TList; // or TIdContextList in modern Indy versions
  I: Integer;
  Client: TClientConnection;
begin
  List := Server.Contexts.LockList;
  try
    for I := 0 to List.Count - 1 do
    begin
      Client := TClientConnection(TIdContext(List.Items[I]));
      if Client.uuid = idtodiscnnect then
      begin
        Client.ForceDisconnect := True; // <-- don't actually disconnect here, just signal it
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Server.Contexts.UnlockList;
  end;
end;

...

procedure TMyForm.ServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  (AContext as TClientConnection).LastSendRecv := Ticks64;
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadTimeout := 30000;
end;

procedure TMyForm.ServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Client: TClientConnection;
  CMD: String;
  Cache, OutboundCmds: TStringList;
  I: integer;
  Len: Integer;
begin
  Client := AContext as TClientConnection;

  if Client.ForceDisconnect then // <-- do the actual disconnect here
  begin
    AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
    Exit;
  end;

  Len := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size;
  if Len >= 200000 then
  begin
    AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
    Exit;
  end;

  // check for pending outbound commands...
  OutboundCmds := nil;
  try
    Cache := Connection.OutboundCache.Lock;
    try
      if Cache.Count > 0 then
      begin
        OutboundCmds := TStringList.Create;
        OutboundCmds.Assign(Cache);
        Cache.Clear;
      end;
    finally
      Connection.OutboundCache.Unlock;
    end;

    if OutboundCmds <> nil then
    begin
      for I := 0 to OutboundCmds.Count - 1 do
      begin
        if Client.ForceDisconnect then // <-- and here, for good measure
        begin
          AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
          Exit;
        end;
        AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(OutboundCmds.Strings[I]);
      end;
      Connection.LastSendRecv := Ticks64;
    end;

  finally
    if OutboundCmds <> nil then
    begin
      for I := 0 to OutboundCmds.Count - 1 do
      begin
        OutboundCmds.Objects[I].Free;
      end;
    end;
    OutboundCmds.Free;
  end;

  // check for a pending inbound command...
  if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
  begin
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(100);
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDisconnect;

    if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
    begin
      // if the client wants to stay connected, it should
      // send a command every so often...
      if GetElapsedTicks(Client.LastSendRecv) >= 30000 then
      begin
        AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  CMD := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
  Client.LastSendRecv := Ticks64;

  ...
end;
```

Comment: sometimes connection keep stuck i did the same onexecute event in your answer

Comment: @madammar then use the debugger, or logging messages, to figure out where it is getting stuck.

Comment: i tried to log that in memo the disconnect procedure always executed and the uuid of the client arrived and the forcedisconnect boolean has set to True

Comment: @madammar 1) you cant access UI controls in a worker thread without syncing with the main UI thread, and the TCP server events are fired in threads. 2) debug your OnExecute event code, not your disconnect code.

Comment: i don't have any UI in the form , i'have also added critical section to the memo to record the log , i get more deep and running the server into the debugger without any exception raised . i think the second check of `if GetElapsedTicks(Client.LastSendRecv) >= 30000 then
      begin
        AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
        Exit;
      end;`  should be replaced with forceconnect boolean ? i am not sure but iam on the test with this now

Comment: @madammar "*i don't have any UI in the form*" - a Memo is a UI control, so you have a UI. "*i'have also added critical section to the memo to record the log*" - you cant sync access to the UI using a critical section. You have to delegate code to execute in the main UI thread, such as via `TThread.Synchronize()`, `TThread.Queue()`, `TIdSync`, `TIdNotify`, `SendMessage()`, `PostMessage()`, etc. "*i think the second check of `if GetElapsedTicks(Client.LastSendRecv) >= 30000 then ...` should be replaced with forceconnect boolean ?*" - no, it should be checking if no data is exchanged in 30 sec.

Comment: i meant before logging i weren't even use a memo in my form . i added the memo to debug this specific  problem i mean with or without UI in form. this problem is accrue only with clients that shutsdown there routers suddenly or got disconnected from there isp  any one else can be disconnected normally . i dont have the idea on how to effectively disconnect the abnormal disconnected client i think about using a timer on the server but i am confused

Comment: @madammar the code is already using a timer of sorts (the ticks check). You might also consider setting the `IOHandler.ReadTimeout` property as well. And maybe even TCP keep alives as well. Timeouts are the only way to deal with *abnormal* disconnects in a timely manner.

Comment: I have a similar situation where the OnExcecute kept on being triggered after calling AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear() and AContext.Connection.Disconnect().  The OnExcecute kept on being triggerd.
Adding AContext.Connection.Socket.Close() seems to solve this.

Comment: @vincent `Disconnect()` calls `IOHandler.Close()` internally (`Socket` just points to the `IOHandler`). So something else is going on.

Comment: @RemyLebeau
What I see in the debugger is that the OnExecute gets triggered again (and InputBuffer.Size=4) after this code: 
```
if Assigned(AContext.Connection.IOHandler) then AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
AContext.Connection.Disconnect();
Exit;
```

If I add ```AContext.Connection.Socket.Close```  the OnExecute does not get triggered again.

Comment: @vincent The `InputBuffer.Size` can't be `> 0` after calling `InputBuffer.Clear()` unless something is still reading data from the socket into the `InputBuffer` after you have cleared it. In any case, `Connection.Connected()` returns True if the `IOHandler` is still `Opened` and there is unread data in its `InputBuffer`, so that explains why the `OnExecute` event is still looping until you `Close()` the `IOHandler` (which `Disconnect()` does internally, so you need to figure out why that isn't happening). Also, you should `Clear()` the `InputBuffer` *after* `Disconnect()`, not *before*.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  Yes, indeed. I made a little test yesterday, and between the ```InputBuffer.Clear()``` and the ```Disconnect``` the InputBuffer had data again.  I changed the order and cleared the InputBuffer only AFTER the disconnect and the issue was gone.  Thanks for the help!